# how to change the background colour of the icon in custom tab pannel from transperant to grey when selecting an icon in mudblazor?

Tags: tabs, mudblazor, mudselect

I have created a mud custom tab pannel with three icons in this background colour is transparent if i select any one icon the icon background should be chaned to grey even the mouse is out.

```
<MudTabPanel InitiallyExpanded="true" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Size="Size.Small" Class="custom-tab-panel" ToolTip="Menu" >
```

Comment: Do you want to change the background of the icon or do you want to change the background of the Tabpanel?

Comment: background of the tab